# View canvas after click button - App Force close

Tags: android-canvas

```
 public void Pattern(Canvas canvas) {

            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);

            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            paint.setTextSize(22);
            canvas.drawText("movement pattern", 75, 55, paint);


            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);



            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(359, 300 , 4, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(425, 300, 4, paint);
        //  canvas.drawCircle(248, , 4, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(248, 380, 4, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(50, 300, 4, paint);
            //canvas.drawCircle(5421, 6499, 4, paint);
            // draw a thick dashed line,
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawLine(359, 300 , 425, 300,  paint);
            canvas.drawLine(425, 300, 248, 380,  paint);
            //canvas.drawLine(400, 500 ,248, 380,  paint);
            canvas.drawLine(248, 380 , 50, 300,  paint);
            canvas.drawLine(50, 300, 359, 300,  paint);

        }
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BPV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/View"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnShowLocation"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:onClick="Pattern"
    android:text="Pattern" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/PV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BPV"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1" />
```

Basically, at main layout, I have 4 buttons and all works. But except for **BPV button**.
I want to display **Pattern(Canvas canvas)** at **PV** when click **BPV button**. But App force close when click it.

Comment: @trololo my logcat is empty

Answer (score 0):

The method signature of the `Pattern` method is incorrect.
When used as android:onClick in the XML it **must** be `public void Pattern(View view)`

You need to figure out another approach for what you are trying to do, when you click the button you do not have paint access to the canvas of the view.